# Deploying angular app to Azure with Github Actions failed. package.json not found

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, npm, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy an `Angular(10) WebApp` to Azure with CI/CD using the Github Actions but I get an error saying the `package.json` cannot be found while running the `npm install` command.

This is my **yml** file

```
name: Deploy to Azure with Hexa.ru
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
    - release/*

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm install
      run: |
        npm --prefix D:\home\site\wwwroot\SleepDiary\package.json install
    - name: npm build, and deploy
      env:
        AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID }}
        AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD }}
        AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_TENANT: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_TENANT }}
      run: |
        npm run hexa:login
        npm run build -- --prod
        npm run hexa:deploy
```

And the error:

```
Run npm --prefix D:\home\site\wwwroot\SleepDiary\package.json install
  npm --prefix D:\home\site\wwwroot\SleepDiary\package.json install
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm\cache\_logs\2020-09-28T06_32_50_591Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I also tried without the parameter `--prefix` and the error remains (similar)

```
Run npm install
  npm install
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\SleepDiary\SleepDiary\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\a\SleepDiary\SleepDiary\package.json'
npm WARN SleepDiary No description
npm WARN SleepDiary No repository field.
npm WARN SleepDiary No README data
npm WARN SleepDiary No license field.
```

I've checked the path in the azure console of my appservice and it should be
`D:\home\site\wwwroot\SleepDiary` (you can ignore the `dist` folder, I created a kudu deployment that works just for testing but I want to achieve the same result with github actions)

[image]

Any idea how to make it run?

**UPDATE**

I moved the code to the upper folder in the repository as suggested but the github action still cannot continue. It gets stuck after the `ng test` It doesn't throw any error, just remains there for more than hour.

```
  Run npm install
  npm install
  npm run build --if-present
  npm run test --if-present
  shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall D:\a\SleepDiary\SleepDiary\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> @angular/cli@10.1.3 postinstall D:\a\SleepDiary\SleepDiary\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1494 packages from 1234 contributors and audited 1499 packages in 79.932s
found 0 vulnerabilities


> sleep-diary@0.0.0 build D:\a\SleepDiary\SleepDiary
> ng build

Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/clipboard : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/platform : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/bidi : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/collections : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/scrolling : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/drag-drop : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/observers : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/a11y : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations/browser : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/forms : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/portal : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/overlay : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/form-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/autocomplete : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/badge : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/layout : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/bottom-sheet : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/card : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/checkbox : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/chips : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/button : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/http : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/icon : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/stepper : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/dialog : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/text-field : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/input : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/datepicker : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/accordion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/expansion : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/grid-list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/divider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/list : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/menu : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/progress-spinner : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/radio : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sidenav : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slider : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/slide-toggle : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/snack-bar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/select : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tooltip : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/paginator : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/sort : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/table : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tabs : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/toolbar : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/tree : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/material/tree : es2015 as esm2015

chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 35.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 139 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 168 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 6.03 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-09-29T06:44:33.715Z - Hash: d5c650f4ac85337a8e18 - Time: 17250ms

> sleep-diary@0.0.0 test D:\a\SleepDiary\SleepDiary
> ng test

Compiling @angular/core/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/common/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
29 09 2020 06:44:54.035:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
29 09 2020 06:44:54.041:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.2.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
29 09 2020 06:44:54.042:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
29 09 2020 06:44:54.047:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
29 09 2020 06:45:03.234:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
29 09 2020 06:45:07.874:INFO [Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10)]: Connected on socket zXnYWqIDSNfH7VtIAAAA with id 11289129
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.003 secs)
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 2 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.003 secs)
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 3 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.004 secs)
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 4 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.004 secs)
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.087 secs)
ERROR: ''mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.087 secs)
ERROR: ''mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: ''mat-sidenav' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.087 secs)
ERROR: ''mat-sidenav' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
ERROR: ''mat-sidenav-content' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 5 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.087 secs)
ERROR: ''mat-sidenav-content' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-content' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-content' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.'
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 6 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.104 secs)
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 7 of 7 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.11 secs)
Chrome 85.0.4183.102 (Windows 10): Executed 7 of 7 SUCCESS (0.14 secs / 0.11 secs)
TOTAL: 7 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 7 SUCCESS
```

Comment: In the last screenshot you provided, the SleepDiary folder shouldn't exist, so that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question, obviously, is the wrong path of the `package.json` file.

Why is your `package.json` file in the `SleepDiary` directory.

**Under normal circumstances, the file path should look like this.**

Under Linux, the package.json file should exist in the `wwwroot` folder after release, and it should also be like this locally:

[image]

[image]

The solution is to move the package.json file out of the SleepDiary folder. Because it is not clear why you have the SleepDiary folder, and what is inside, please try it first. If it is convenient, you can update the screenshot of your directory structure. In the question, we can help you better.

[image]

Under normal circumstances, it is recommended to deploy the ng10 project through `FTP` or `zip`, because after personal testing, no matter under the `linux` or `windows` platform, the ng build command will be executed, and the content in the dist folder generated after the build is really to be released. document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I moved the code to the upper folder in my repository and now the npm commands work, but the deployment still gets stuck after the test command. 
I will update the question with this issue.Maybe you can help with this too.

Comment: @blfuentes Can you `ng build` or `ng test` successfully in local?

Comment: Yes, I can do both without problem in local development. I am wondering if this is a problem related to the service plan (Free tier) as I see this in the environment info `d:\local usage: 500 MB total; 0 MB free` I have removed the `ng test` step and the build fails because of not enough space on disk.

Comment: @blfuentes I want to tell you that even if you are now running properly in the github action, your webapp still cannot be accessed normally.

Comment: @blfuentes I have personally tested, and the current angular 10 version of the project, I found that only the contents of the deployment dist folder can be accessed normally.

Comment: @blfuentes  The function of continuous deployment seems to be currently not supported in angular 10. You can create a demo test, do not use your current project. If the test result is as I described, then there is no need to continue to worry about the error message in the action.

Comment: Well, Actually after removing the `ng test` and changing the app service plan to one with more space available it worked, but the site was only accesible after changing the `path map` of the app in azure to point to `site\wwwroot\dist\SleepDiary` so... this is by default broken. KuDu seems to work better and is quite faster.